# Spring Security HTTP 403 Forbidden

Tags: spring, rest, jersey, spring-security-rest

I've been trying to secure a rest-api resource. However, it seems that the `/auth/**` REST-API always throws 403 Forbidden even though i have permitted it on the configuration. see below

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    logger.info("Setting Endpoint Security.");

    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .csrf().disable();

}
```

This is on the `WebSecurityConfig`class extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

Here is the spring security debug logs

```
2018-11-18 20:14:27.923  INFO 8476 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] Spring Security Debugger                 : 

************************************************************

Request received for POST '/api/v1/auth/login':

org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@1a183946

servletPath:/api/v1
pathInfo:/auth/login
headers: 
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
cache-control: no-cache
postman-token: 5bd56859-b8e9-4ebf-977c-452f1bce837e
user-agent: PostmanRuntime/7.4.0
accept: */*
host: localhost:8080
cookie: JSESSIONID=D80F964AA5B53DC7F20ACF59606FA719
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
content-length: 29
connection: keep-alive


Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  LogoutFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]


************************************************************
```

and here is the resource i am trying to access

```
@Path("/auth")
@Component
public class Auth {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Auth.class);

    @POST
    @Path("/login")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public Response login(@FormParam("username") String user, 
                          @FormParam("password") String pass) {
        logger.info("Form-data [username] {}",user);
        logger.info("Form-data [password] {}",pass);
        return Response.ok().build();
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/logout")
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public String logout() {
        return "Login!";
    } 

}
```

Just so we are clear, i am using Jersey + Spring Boot

Here is Jersey Config

```
@Configuration
@ApplicationPath("api/v1")
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig{
    public JerseyConfig() {

    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void setUp() {
        register(Wish.class);
        register(Auth.class);
        register(User.class);
        register(GenericExceptionMapper.class);
    }
}
```

Now, as what i understand on the `http` method series in `configure`method.

First, http auhthorizes request, matches `/auth/**` and permits it, other requests needs to be authorized. However, when i try requesting `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/auth/login` it always returns `403 Forbidden`.

Can somebody point out the mistakes or maybe my understanding is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your configuration only permit http://localhost:8080/auth/** not http://localhost:8080/api/v1/auth/**,

so change it to something like:

```
.antMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**").permitAll()
```

it should be the first one in the order

Comment: still the same, both `/api/v1/auth/**` and `**/auth/**` does not work

Comment: sorry scratch that, didn't notice i lack `v1` i used /api/v/auth/** only. Why does `**/auth/**` dont work?